# Tell pylint what the return type of a method is

Tags: python, pylint

To give details: this is a constrained environment with Python 2.7.14, Pylint 1.8.1, and Astroid 1.6.0 and various other modules, but I can't easily install new modules such as `mypy` (not even with virtualenv) or make major changes to the codebase.

Due to https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/400 I'm getting errors from pylint on some of my code.  I've worked around this issue in a hacky way (by removing the integer argument to the wait() method) and now I don't get errors, but no checking is done (pylint can't determine what the type of the variable is at all).

What I'd really like to do is tell pylint what the return type is.  I've tried reading the Astroid docs, perusing the various astroid/brains files, and looking at other SO questions and answers such as [Set multiple inferred types based on arguments for pylint plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46801978/939557) and [pylint, coroutines, decorators and type inferencing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38087760/939557) but I guess I'm just not getting it.  I have added my own `load-plugins` and I know it's loaded during pylint (because it had syntax errors at first :)).  But I'm just not sure what it needs to do.

Suppose I had this code:

```
class Peer(object):
    def get_domain(self):
        return "foo"

class TestListener(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._latest = None

    def get(self, timeout):
        # tricks here
        return self._latest

    def peer_joined(self, peer):
        self._latest = peer

peer = TestListener().get(3)
print(peer.get_domain())
print(peer.get_foo())
```

During `# tricks here` we are really waiting on a `threading.Event()` during which another thread will invoke `peer_joined()` and pass an object of type `Peer()`, but pylint doesn't grok this.

What I'd like to do is annotate the `TestListener.get()` method to tell pylint that it will return a `Peer` object, so that pylint will catch the error in the second print call.

I've tried this but clearly I'm missing something fundamental, since it appears my transform method is never even invoked (if I put a bogus method call there no error is printed):

```
from astroid import MANAGER, register_module_extender
from astroid.builder import AstroidBuilder

def TestListener_transform():
    return AstroidBuilder(MANAGER).string_build('''
class TestListener(object):
    def get(self, timeout):
        return Peer()
''')

register_module_extender(MANAGER, 'TestListener', TestListener_transform)

# for pylint load-plugins
def register(linter):
    pass
```

Comment: I think mypy (static typing) would be a better tool for this. Have you considered that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the standard Python docstring format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898572/what-is-the-standard-python-docstring-format)

Comment: Unfortunately for me I'm in a constrained environment where I can't easily add lots of new modules, and pylint is what I have available.

Comment: Adding a docstring didn't help; see the answer below.  So I don't think this is a duplicate.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
def get(self, timeout):
    """
    :param timeout: How many seconds to wait
    :type timeout: int
    :rtype: threading.Event
    """
    # tricks here
    return self._latest
```

This is a reStructuredText format for writing a python docstring (a multiline string that appear right after function definition.
You can document there all parameter types, and what the function return along with their datatypes.

pylint can parse that docstring to figure out the datatype of that function's return value.

This stackoverflow answer has more comprehensive explanation
[What is the standard Python docstring format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898572/what-is-the-standard-python-docstring-format)

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I agree with you, was a bit lazy.
I've updated the answer. Thanks  yivi

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me.  Does it work for you?  I added the docstring with `:rtype: Peer` then enabled the `pylint.extensions.docparams` plugin in my pylintrc file.  I know it worked because it warned me about a missing `:return:` description in the doc string.  However, pylint still did not emit any messages about the incorrect  method `peer.get_dom()`.

Comment: another thing you can try is using assert.
`assert isinstance(peer, Peer)` before calling `peer.get_dom()`

Comment: Hi @Ramast; unfortunately that won't work.  I'm trying to get pylint to see that the returned type of the `get()` method is a `Peer` object, so that it can check all the methods etc. used by the returned objects.  Pylint doesn't actually run the code, it's a static type checker, so assert has no effect.  The goal is to find errors in the code without having to run all branches of the code; if I run the code I don't need the assert because Python will fail anyway (as there's no `get_dom()` method in a `Peer` object).

Comment: I understand that pylint doesn't execute the code but I thought it uses `assert isinstance` as type hint. I couldn't reproduce that assumption, probably I mixed up pylint with pycharm https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205988704-Using-asserts-for-type-hinting

Answer (score 0):

One thing to mention is that pylint currently has limited capabilities for type-checking, as those seen in mypy. It relies more on inferring  values and types without type hints, although the intent is to have support for PEP-484 typing at some point.

Now regarding the question, I see that you are using a module extender, while in fact you should use a class transform, as in:

```
astroid.MANAGER.register_transform(astroid.ClassDef,  _class_transform,
                                   optional_transform_predicate)
```